# How a pattern can be applied for a spring boot application running in 2 modes initialize and server?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am seeking a pattern 2 days for develoing my spring boot web on 2 modes of initialize and server.

I'll get a parameter from program arguments or yaml file.

If this parameter is initialize program running on initialize mode. Initialize mode will do some settings, creating hibernate table, adding default users to db after that stop. Yes, I'll run and finish this works after that it'll stop.

If this parameter is server, program run normally spring boot web application.

Do you know a pattern like I said or Could offer any solution to me?

Thanks.

Comment: its sounds like you're looking for something more like liquibase or flyway to control database changes/versioning of the database.

Comment: May you can achieve this by spring profiles. Create 2 profiles. 1 - for development and 2 - for production. When you want run the development pass profile as development.

Answer (score 1):

**[Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles)**

Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments. Any @Component or @Configuration can be marked with @Profile to limit when it is loaded:

n the normal Spring way, you can use a spring.profiles.active Environment property to specify which profiles are active. You can specify the property in any of the usual ways, for example you could include it in your application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb
```

or specify on the command line using the switch

```
--spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb.
```

You can programmatically set active profiles by calling **SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(…​)** before your application runs. It is also possible to activate profiles using Spring’s ConfigurableEnvironment interface.

Profile-specific variants of both application.properties (or application.yml) and files referenced via @ConfigurationProperties are considered as files are loaded. See Section 24.4, “[Profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)” for details.

In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific properties can also be defined using the naming convention application-{profile}.properties. The Environment has a set of default profiles (by default [default]) which are used if no active profiles are set (i.e. if no profiles are explicitly activated then properties from application-default.properties are loaded).

Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the non-specific ones irrespective of whether the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

If several profiles are specified, a last wins strategy applies. For example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are added after those configured via the SpringApplication API and therefore take precedence.

The following is example of yml file. which contains 2 profiles.

```
#Production Configuration values
spring:
  profiles: prod  

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/production

    username: userName
    password: password
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
---

#Development  Configuration values
spring:
  profiles: development

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/development?useSSL=false
    username: userName
    password: password

... Other settings can be here like creating tables, configure liquibase or hibernate auto ddl to true.
```

To run your project with development mode,you can run the below

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=development springbootproject.jar
```

Comment: Firstly thank you so much. Ok I got it. And how to implement what I asked. For example, if programme run on development profile programme just run once and after done the hibernate works(table creates,updates etc.) I want to add default admin user and give permissions to this user and programme stop. This mode will not serve web pages. After done working of development profile I'll run product pfrofile and this profile serve web pages and I'll develop web pages. How can I do this?